# Exporting Data from sas into CSV file

Tags: sas, export

I am trying to download a file from SAS and import it to Hadoop.
Its a huge dataset - 6GB.
When I export the sas dataset to csv file and then import back to sas.(as I was facing few in issues in hadoop, I tried importing back to SAS and verify values). The import shows problems in the dataset in the same tool itself..
The column values are jumbled up.
Few columns have junk values, few columns are overlapped
How can I export the dataset in csv format with the column values intact.

```
filename output 'AAA.csv' encoding="utf-8";


Proc export data= input_data
            outfile= output
            dbms = CSV;
run;
```

Comment: You need to show some example data that does not work. Remember CSV files are pure text so there is nothing to tell the reader what type of values to expect in each field.

Comment: How can a column "overlap"?  What does that mean?

Comment: Overlap Example : Col1 --> A, Col2 --> B...after import Col1 -->AB and Col2-->null

Comment: So for the overlap example here is one possible cause.  If you have one column whose value starts with single quote and other column whose value ends with single quote SAS will output those without adding any quoting.  But then when SAS reads it in it will look like one long quoted string (SAS allows either single or double quotes to be used to quote the field values in a CSV file). 7 fields might yield line like `1,'beginning,3,4,ending',6,7` that will be read as 4 fields.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but try removing any end of line characters that might exist in your character strings.

For example you could use a simple data step view to convert the strings on the fly.  Here is one that replaces any CR or LF character with a pipe character.

```
data for_export / view=for_export;
  set input_data;
  array _c _character_;
  do over _c;
    _c = translate(_c,'||','0D0A'x);
  end;
run;
proc export data=for_export outfile=output dbms=CSV;
run;
```

You might also watch out for backslash characters. Some readers try to interpret those as an escape character.